# Efficient way to work with large number of dictionary

Tags: python

I have list of dictionary in which there can be multiple keys and if key exist then the value of key require operation based on the key. Currently my code iterate all the dictionary and check if the the keys exists and then do the operation. Is there any other way to achieve the same efficiently because I am observing with list of 250+ dictionary, the execution is taking considerable amount of time. I cannot parallelize the execution also. The **set** method is wrapper to execute command.

class Exec(object):

```
def _execute(self, mappers):
    self.cmds = list()
    for mapper in mappers:
        self._prepare_cmd(mapper)

    for cmd in self.cmds:
        self.set(cmd.split())

def _prepare_cmd(self, mapper):
    if mapper['pos']:
        cmd1 = 'set position ' + str(mapper['pos'])
        self.cmds.append(cmd1)

    if mapper['distance']:
        cmd2 = 'set distance ' + str(mapper['distance'])
        self.cmds.append(cmd2)

    if mapper['user']:
        cmd3 = 'set privilege ' + str(mapper['user'])
        self.cmds.append(cmd3)

    if mapper['deny']:
        cmd4 = 'set access ' + mapper['deny']
        self.cmds.append(cmd4)

    if mapper['instance_of']:
        cmd5 = 'set instance_o f' + mapper['instance_of']
        self.cmds.append(cmd5)

    if mapper['is_shared']:
        cmd6 = 'set allow_shared ' + mapper['is_shared']
        self.cmds.append(cmd6)
```

Comment: Please include your code. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh for that it was downvoted. I will include code.

Comment: What are the keys, and which type are the values? (i.e. are both int?). Also, include sample code of exactly what you are trying to improve.

Comment: "Currently my code iterate all the dictionary and check if the the keys exists": if you iterate over the dict, then the key will always exist. You'll need to be clearer what you mean by "if the key exists".

Comment: @MitchWheat I have added code. Can you explain ?

Comment: You have different dictionary keys mapped to different commands. Why don't you have dictionary keys like `'set access'` rather than `'deny'`. Maybe that way you could vectorize something. Additionally, why some of the values are casted to `str` while others don't? To me, this looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @imaluengo the cast operation is done bcoz the datatype is different and we can't concatenate with str to any other different type. And yes its not XY problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. This is not a very efficient way of handling things in python. Why do you have dictionaries with different keys than commands in the first place? If you had the same keys the `_prepare_cmd` could be reduced to just `self.cmds += ['set {} {}'.format(k, str(v)) for k, v in mapper.iteritems()]`.

Comment: Bcoz the REST API exposed is of 3rd party and I don't have hold to make it compatible with my environment. The only way I can do is to read and change them according to my underlying environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really need to do it like that, you could do something like:

1) Define a mapping between your keys and the target api:

```
mapping = {
    'pos' : 'position',
    'distance' : 'distance',
    'user' : 'privilege',
    'deny' : 'access',
    'instance_of' : 'instance_of',
    'is_shared' : 'allow_shared'
}
```

2) replace your `_prepare_cmd` function:

```
def _prepare_cmd(self, one_dict):
    self.cmds += ['set {} {}'.format(mapping[k], str(v) for k, v in one_dict.items()]
```

Assuming `mapping` contains an entry for each of the possible keys of your dicts.